# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Opt-in Process

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

If I create an SMS using the SMS opt-in template in Mobile Connect, will this store all the contacts that respond in a separate list so I can target that list with a campaign in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this use case by making a [mobile filtered list](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_create_a_filtered_list_of_contacts.htm&type=5), where you can filter on keyword and status to create your sendable audience

Comment: So am I correct in saying you would use the Opt-in template to "harvest" your opt-ins, and attribute a 'Next Keyword' to the responses. Then when creating a sendable list you just filter by the keyword you set?